# Laravel Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\route' not found

Tags: php, laravel-7

Trying to call a route from redirectTo() function. Getting this error message

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\route' not found error

Both routes are in web.php

```
Route::get('/storeapproval',function() {
            return view('auth.storeNotApproved');});//I can call this

Route::post('auth/verifyMobilenumber/{user_id}')->name('auth.verifyMobilenumber'); //but this gives Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\route' not found error


public function redirectTo()
    {
return '/storeapproval'; //this one works fine

     return route::post('auth.verifyMobilenumber',array('user_id'=>$userid,'role'=>"RESOWN",'phone'=>$user->email));   **// this one gives Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\route' not found error**
}
```

Comment: try `return redirect()->route(`

Comment: You have typo mistake. Please change it from ```route::post``` to ```Route::post```

Comment: tried now I am getting "Undefined property: Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::$route"

Comment: @SohailAhmed changed and still the same error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\route' not found error"

Comment: _Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\route'_ You're still missing an uppercase `R` somewhere else. It needs to be `Route` not `route`

Comment: @SelsonsSoftware Would you please share a log of this error, so we can try to fix it?

Comment: here `Route::post('auth/verifyMobilenumber/{user_id}')->name('auth.verifyMobilenumber');` where is the function or the controller method ?

Answer (score 0):

I know that when you define a path, you have to define a method to execute,

So this line :

```
Route::post('auth/verifyMobilenumber/{user_id}')->name('auth.verifyMobilenumber');
```

should be

```
Route::post('auth/verifyMobilenumber/{user_id}','ControllerName@methodName')
->name('auth.verifyMobilenumber');
```

or

```
Route::post('auth/verifyMobilenumber/{user_id}',function($user_id) {
            //some processing
            return view('some.view');
})->name('auth.verifyMobilenumber');
```